# How can I stop bars from overlapping

Tags: php, barcode

I have this barcode generation [code](http://pastebin.com/2uJENs3u).

The actual generation part is:

```
$valoare = substr($code_string, ($position-1), 1);
            if($valoare==1)
                $cur_size = 0.5;
            elseif($valoare==2)
                $cur_size = 1;
            elseif($valoare==3)
                $cur_size = 1.5;
            elseif($valoare==3)
                $cur_size = 2;
            if ( strtolower($orientation) == "horizontal" )
                draw_bar($cur_size, ($position % 2 == 0 ? $white : $black) );
```

Function draw_bar:

```
function draw_bar($cur_size, $color){

    ?>
    <div style="width:<?php echo $cur_size?>; height:40px; background-color:<?php echo $color; ?>;float:left; position:relative"></div>
    <?php
}
```

For big values of `$cur_size` the generated barcode is correct.
For smaller sizes, the bars overlap, so instead of two small bars separated by a white space, I get one big bar. The more I zoom in, the barcode resizes to a correct form.

Here are two images, the first one is incorrect, the second in correct, after zooming 200%.

[image]

[image]

How can I stop bars from overlapping at small sizes?

Thank you!

Comment: try with removing height, width or any css on bar code image

Comment: when I remove the height, the barcodes do not appear at all (I have no idea why it makes the height 0)

Comment: check https://github.com/picqer/php-barcode-generator

Comment: This is the first generator I tried and encountered the same problem :(